# update table from another table's data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables : customers (customer,city_name,postal_code) and postal_codes(city_name,postal_code).

In the customers table the postal_code entries are missing but the city is there.

How can I update the customers table from the postal_codes table so the missing postal_code gets updated in the customers table where the postal_code is missing?

This may be a duplicate but I could not make work any of the suggestions from similar threads. They all use some kind of abbreviations for table names which I find hard to follow.

Tried this but it does not seem to work :

```
UPDATE  customers
SET     postal_code = postal_codes.postal_code
FROM    postal_codes.postal_code INNER JOIN postal_codes.city_name ON customers.city_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I recall SQLite does not support the `update ... from join` syntax, but this query should work for you:

```
UPDATE customers
SET postal_code = (
  SELECT postal_codes.postal_code 
  FROM postal_codes
  WHERE postal_codes.city_name = customers.city_name 
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM postal_codes
  WHERE postal_codes.city_name = customers.city_name
    AND postal_codes.postal_code <> customers.postal_code
);
```

Comment: @user3927897 AFAIK this syntax should work with SQLite; try removing the `AND postal_codes.postal_code <> customers.postal_code` near the end and see if that makes it work.

Comment: @user3927897 Are you sure that the remaining ~1700 rows have city_names that match between the tables?